# Peut-on écrire « Il y a des travaux rue des Saules/ autoroute Jean-Lesage » sans la préposition « dans » ou « sur » devant le nom de la rue?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation

L’usage nous permet d’écrire « demeurer » et « habiter » sans employer de préposition devant le nom des voies de communication. Est-ce que cet usage s’étend à l’ensemble des énonciations comportant un nom de rue, de boulevard ou d’avenue?

Exemple: Il demeure/ habite rue des Saules.

Il y a des travaux [sur l’] autoroute Jean-Lesage?

Comment: Même si autoroute est un mot, tel que _gare_, une différence c'est qu'une gare est très localisée, alors qu'une autoroute s'étend. Est-ce que l'on prétend que l'usage de l'omission de la préposition dans le syntagme pour une _destination_ permet de répondre à la question pour un objet qui s'étend ou s'agit-il d'un cas où la réponse n'est pas reliée à la question de l'omission mais à autre chose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oui, je ne vois pas pourquoi on ne pourrais pas.

On peut se passer de préposition dans d'autres cas comme :

> Je l'ai croisé route des crêtes.

> Ça bouchonne périph' Nord.

> On se retrouve escalier C.

et donc :

> Il y a des travaux autoroute de Normandie.

pour Jean Lesage, je ne sais pas ;-)

Comment: Ouais mais [Jean-Lesage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoroute_20_(Qu%C3%A9bec)), c'est la 20, elle fait la distance entre Paris et Genève. Je ne sais pas si il y a déjà eu un moment où il n'y avait pas de travaux là hahahah. Ce qui est sans doute usuel c'est « su' 'a 20 à (la) hauteur (de) des Saules ».

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie: Effectivement c’est la formulation la plus répandue à l’oral au Québec! Mais, pour en revenir à ma question, est-ce qu’il est possible (correct) de se passer de prépositions devant les noms de voie de communication dans tous les cas de figure, comme « Il y a des travaux autoroute Jean-Lesage?

Comment: À l’oreille, en tout cas, à mon oreille, l’énonciation « Il y a des travaux rue des Saules » me semble sonner bien, mais à l’inverse, « Il y a des travaux autoroute Jean-Lesage » me semble assonant. Je ne veux pas m’en remettre à mes sens pour juger de l’exactitude d’une construction. Alors, qu’en dirait monsieur Grevisse s’il était encore de ce monde? Serait-elle admissible à l’écrit ou jugée fautive?